# Crashing at queue.sync { self._state }

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I'm trying to create an async subclass of Operation.
The code crashes on the getter of the "state" Property.
I have found an article which solves the async Subclass, but i'm curios as to why a crash happens at queue.sync { self._state }
The willSet and DidSet of the _state property is called and the control moves to the getter state where it crashes
[image of the crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKKKy.png)

```
class ConcurrentOperation: Operation {
        private enum State: String {
            case ready = "isReady"
            case executing = "isExecuting"
            case finished = "isFinished"
        }
    
        private var _state: State = .ready {
            willSet {
                willChangeValue(forKey: newValue.rawValue)
                willChangeValue(forKey: _state.rawValue)
            }
            didSet {
                didChangeValue(forKey: _state.rawValue)
                didChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.rawValue)
            }
        }
    
        private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.concurrentOperation.chanakkya",  attributes: .concurrent)
    
        private var state: State {
            get {
                queue.sync { self._state }
            }
            set {
                queue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
                    self._state = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    
        override var isReady: Bool {
            super.isReady && state == .ready
        }
    
        override var isExecuting: Bool {
            state == .executing
        }
    
        override var isFinished: Bool {
            state == .finished
        }
    
        override func start() {
            guard !isCancelled else {
                finish()
                return
            }
    
            if !isExecuting {
                state = .executing
            }
    
            main()
        }
    
        override func main() {
            fatalError()
        }
    
        func finish() {
            if isExecuting {
                state = .finished
            }
        }
    
        override func cancel() {
            super.cancel()
            finish()
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your stack trace on the left, it will show you that you are in the middle of `state.setter` (#27 in the trace of thread 6’s stack) when it tries to call `state.getter` (#6 in the stack trace). In this case, this is caused by an observer that is checking `isExecuting` (#7 in the stack trace). More generally, this can be caused by the use of KVO [observing options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyvalueobservingoptions) that may choose to fetch `.new`/`.old` values as part of the KVO notification.

[image]

Bottom line, you are synchronizing the `setter` which simultaneously invokes and prevents subsequent synchronized `getter`.

---

There are a variety of solutions:

1. You can use a recursive lock. (Generally, recursive locks indicate code smell, but this is one scenario where they may be appropriate.)

   ```swift
   private let lock = NSRecursiveLock()

   private var _state: State = .ready {
       willSet {
           willChangeValue(forKey: newValue.rawValue)
           willChangeValue(forKey: _state.rawValue)
       }
       didSet {
           didChangeValue(forKey: _state.rawValue)
           didChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.rawValue)
       }
   }

   private var state: State {
       get { lock.withLock { _state } }
       set { lock.withLock { _state = newValue } }
   }
   ```

   Personally, I would move the manual KVO into the computed property:

   ```swift
   private let lock = NSRecursiveLock()

   private var _state: State = .ready

   private var state: State {
       get { 
           lock.withLock { _state }
       }
       set { 
           lock.withLock {
               let oldValue = _state
               willChangeValue(forKey: newValue.rawValue)
               willChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.rawValue)
               _state = newValue
               didChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.rawValue)
               didChangeValue(forKey: newValue.rawValue)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can move the manual KVO notifications out of synchronized `set`, eliminating the need for recursive locking:

   ```
   private let lock = NSLock()

   private var _state: State = .ready

   private var state: State {
       get {
           lock.withLock { _state }
       }
       set {
           willChangeValue(forKey: newValue.rawValue)
           willChangeValue(forKey: state.rawValue)

           lock.withLock {
               let oldValue = _state
               _state = newValue
           }

           didChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.rawValue)
           didChangeValue(forKey: newValue.rawValue)
       }
   }
   ```

   At this point, you can use whatever synchronization mechanism you want.
3. You can just use the `dynamic` qualifier and let the compiler generate all the KVO for you. And then, adopting a pattern outlined in the code samples that once accompanied [Advanced NSOperations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/), you can use either `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue` (or `keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsReady`, `keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsExecuting`, and `keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished`) to make sure that the `state` KVO notifications propagate to `isReady`, `isExecuting` and `isFinished`).

   ```swift
   class ConcurrentOperation: Operation {
       @objc private enum State: Int {
           case ready, executing, finished
       }

       private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.concurrentOperation.chanakkya")

       private var _state: State = .ready

       @objc dynamic private var state: State {
           get { queue.sync { _state } }
           set { queue.sync { _state = newValue } }
       }

       open override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
           if [#keyPath(isReady), #keyPath(isFinished), #keyPath(isExecuting)].contains(key) {
               return [#keyPath(state)]
           }

           return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
       }

       override var isReady:     Bool { super.isReady && state == .ready }
       override var isExecuting: Bool { state == .executing }
       override var isFinished:  Bool { state == .finished }

       override func start() {
           guard !isCancelled else {
               finish()
               return
           }

           if !isExecuting {
               state = .executing
           }

           main()
       }

       override func main() {
           fatalError()
       }

       func finish() {
           if isExecuting {
               state = .finished
           }
       }

       override func cancel() {
           super.cancel()
           finish()
       }
   }
   ```

   The `dynamic` property with `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue` ensures that the relevant KVO notifications take place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a temp variable

```swift
private var state: State {
            get {
                var temp: State!
                queue.sync { 
                   temp  = self._state 
                }
                return temp
            }
            set {
                queue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
                    self._state = newValue
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it still crashes. i think the crash might have to do something with the operation lifecycle, A KVO getting called or something